# impoertent of using synchronized map (meaing hashtable or ConcurrentMap) in a multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading

can someone show example why it is impoertent to use only synchronized map (meaing hashtable or ConcurrentMap) in a multithreaded application ?
I understand why it is impoertent to synchronized the application methods that doing actions on the map , but why the map itself need to be synchronized ?

I tried this :

```
public class MapTest {

    private static final TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public synchronized void run() {
                map.put("pp", "ww");

            }
        };

        Thread r = new Thread() {
            public synchronized void run() {
                System.out.println("s:" + map.get("pp"));
            }
        };

        t.start();
        r.start();

    }
}
```

but I'm always getting same "good" result : s:ww allthoght the map is not synchronized

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

Comment: what do you think about toilets with no locks on the doors?